# Hide button inside a gridview row

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, gridview

I need to show/hide a `Button` inside a `ASP.NET` `GridView` row.
This the code related to `GridView`, please consider that grid is placed inside a `FormView`

```
 <asp:FormView
      ID="_fvFormData"
      runat="server"
      DataKeyNames="id"
      DataSourceID="_sdsData"
      DefaultMode="Edit" 
      Enabled="false" 
      Visible="false"
      Width="100%">
      <EditItemTemplate>
          <asp:Table runat="server">
              <asp:TableRow>
                  <asp:TableCell>
                       <asp:GridView
                            ID="_gvAttachments" 
                            ClientIDMode="Static"
                            DataKeyNames="id"
                            runat="server"
                            DataSourceID="_sdsAttachments" 
                            AutoGenerateColumns="false"
                            AutoGenerateEditButton="false"
                            EmptyDataText="No attachment."
                            ShowHeader="true" 
                            ShowFooter="true"
                            AllowSorting="true"
                            AllowPaging="false" >
                            <HeaderStyle CssClass="header" />
                            <FooterStyle CssClass="footer" />
                            <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="even" />
                            <RowStyle CssClass="odd" />
                                <Columns>
                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="File">
                                         <ItemTemplate>
                                              <asp:LinkButton 
                                                   ID="_lnkOpenFile"
                                                        ClientIDMode="Static"
                                                        runat="server" 
                                                        Text='<%#Eval("attachment") %>' 
                                                        CommandName="OpenFile" 
                                                        CommandArgument='<%#Eval("id") %>' />
                                                    <br />
                                                    <asp:FileUpload 
                                                        ID="_fuRowAttach" 
                                                        ClientIDMode="Static"
                                                        AllowMultiple="false" 
                                                        onchange="CheckFile(this)" 
                                                        runat="server" />
                                                    &nbsp;
                                                    <asp:Button 
                                                        ID="_btnUpload" 
                                                        ClientIDMode="Static" 
                                                        runat="server" 
                                                        Text="Carica" 
                                                        CommandName="UploadFile" 
                                                        CommandArgument='<%#Eval("id_type")%>'
                                                        CssClass="butt_blu_small" />
                                                </ItemTemplate>
                                                <EditItemTemplate>
                                                    &nbsp;
                                                </EditItemTemplate>
                                            </asp:TemplateField>
                                </Columns>
                   </asp:TableCell>
              </asp:TableRow> 
          </asp:Table>
      </EditItemTemplate>
  </asp:FormView>
```

The javascript code I wrote is the following:

```
 function CheckAttach(item)
 {
     if (item == null)
         return;

     if (isBlank(item.value))
         return;

     var _btnUpload= item.closest("td").find("[id*=_btnUpload]");

     _btnUpload.show();
 }
```

My intention was to show the `_btnUpload` widget only if `_fuRowAttach` has a file attached ... unluckly the `item` element seems not to implement the `.closest()` method hence I cannot locate the upload button.

Is there a way to safely locate `_btnUpload` in this context?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem:

1. first of all we need to 'hide' the `_btnUpload` button . We cannot use the `Visibile` attribute of `asp` tag since it conflicts with attributes management of javascript/jquery.
2. to use `.closest` and `.find` methods we have to obtain a `jquery` object from the referenced `javascript` object.

The first step can be accomplished in several ways . In this case, since the button was present in a unpredictable number of grid rows, I used a class reference:

```
 <asp:Button 
     ID="_btnUpload" 
     ClientIDMode="
     runat="server" 
     Text="Carica" 
     CommandName="UploadFile" 
     CommandArgument='<%#Eval("id_type")%>'
     CssClass="butt_blu_small upload_bott" />
```

and then I hide all elements of such class, in my javascript code:

```
    $('.upload_bott').hide();
```

The javascript event handler then become:

```
function CheckFile(item) {
    if (item == null)
        return;

    var _item = $(item);

    var _btnUpload = _item.closest("tr").find("[id*=_btnUpload]");

    if (isBlank(_item.val()))
    {
         _btnUpload.hide();
         return;
    }

    _btnUpload.show();
}
```